# Code works in Chrome and Firefox but not in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The codes work in Chrome and Firefox but not in IE. Not sure why. Please advise! Thanks

**Background**: select the targeted locale and download the exe file when user click on the "click here to download" button.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <p>Select language:<br />
            <select class="simpleFormSelect" id="h" name="list" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
                <option value="exe download url here">English</option>
                <option value="exe download url here">Arabic</option>
                <option value="exe download url here">Chinese (Hong Kong)</option>
                <option value="exe download url here">Chinese (Simplified)</option>
            </select>
            <input onclick="top.location.href = $('#h').prop('options')[$('#h').prop('selectedIndex')].value;" type="button" value="Click here to Download" /> 
            (Download size: 6 MB)
        </p>
            <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `window.top.location = "NEW_URL"` for the IE. Or, if your code is run from iframe, `parent.location = "NEW_URL"`